# python sched program possible timing issues

Tags: python, pygame, scheduler

So I have a number of events to schedule with varying delays as such :

```
delays = [1,3,5,30, 40, 35, 12, 46, 52]
```

I schedule the delays as:

```
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
for lagtime in delays:
    s.enter(lagtime, 1, self.drawOnCanvas, (arg1, arg2, arg3))
```

The function drawOnCanvas is doing some pygame/opengl operations

The issue is that python time module has precision in seconds and I want to move in milliseconds. I can set the delays to be:

```
delays = [x/1000 for x in delays]
```

The scheduler takes an arugment of time.time and time.sleep. Can I use datetime here instead and will it accomodate it?

Second I am doing some operations with a mouse and it feels like the mouse is being blocked by the scheduler. Is there a way to stop the mouse being blocked?

edit: I actually figured I need a non-blocking scheduler, but the threading method described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) creates a new thread for ever timer event. Is there a way to make that a single thread invocation?

Answer (score 1):

> python time module has precision in seconds

Not on most modern platforms -- timestamps have a fractional part, so while the **unit of measure** is seconds, the **precision** is typically much better than milliseconds.

```
delays = [x/1000 for x in delays]
```

That's OK in Python 3, where `/` is non-truncating.  For safety wrt Python 2, you'd be better off with

```
delays = [x/1000.0 for x in delays]
```

Apart from that, your existing scheduler should work just fine.  The `datetime` module has no `sleep` functionality so it would be a bit of work to shoehorn it in here (though feasible, but I really don't see any motivation to do that work).